# Android assets folder does not contain what I put in there

Tags: android, android-studio, android-assets

I have added a bunch of wave files into my assets directory for loading.

I created assets by right clicking on my res folder in android and going "Add folder -> Assets folder"

It created an assets folder at app\src\main\assets.

I have dragged a bunch of wav files into that assets directory.

But when I go to list all the files in my assets directory, it just lists a single directory called "images".

Observe the following code. There is a message write that only write out "images".

```
    AssetManager assets = LocalApp.getAppContext().getAssets();
    String[] fileList = assets.list("");

    // we assume all the files in the assets are the wav files that we want to load,
    // so attempt to load everythign in assets as a wav
    for (int i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++) {
        Log.e(TAG, "readSamples: file name = "+fileList[i]);
        WavFile wave =  new WavFile(assets.open(fileList[i]));
        samples.add(wave);
    }
```

Comment: did you refresh all your project folders?

Comment: I am unfamiliar with this terminology / process.

Comment: I guess after you add file into new folder, the project does not refresh itself, so you cannot see your wav files?

Comment: What does refresh mean? I have cleaned and rebuilt.....I don't know about this "refresh" term....

Comment: The solution to my problem has nothing to do with android assets, and is based in my WavFile code. Should this question be closed?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can try this:-

```
    String dirFrom = "putYourPathToAssestsFolderHere"
    //if you are in an activity
    Resources res = getResources(); 
    AssetManager assets = res.getAssets();
    String fileList[] = assets.list(dirFrom);

        if (fileList != null)
        {   
            for ( int i = 0;i<fileList.length;i++)
            {
                Log.e(TAG, "readSamples: file name = "+fileList[i]); 
            }
        }
```